# Representing prime numbers as continous bit array in C

Tags: c, algorithm, debugging, gcc, primes

I am trying to make a very large bit array where the position of the bit in memory is the number, and the value of the bit (0 or 1) is the state of that number (prime/not prime). I am trying it like this:

```
#define SIZE 2

int* A = calloc(SIZE, 4);
//retrieve the state of a number (True if not prime, false if prime)
if(A[0] & (1 << 0)){} //will give me the state for 0
if(A[0] & (1 << 1)){} //will give me the state for 1
if(A[0] & (1 << 2)){} //will give me the state for 2
if(A[0] & (1 << 7)){} //will give me the state for 7
if(A[0] & (1 << 8)){} //will give me the state for 8
if(A[0] & (1 << 31)){} //will give me the state for 31

//Now can I do this??
if(A[0] & (1 << 32)){} //will give me the state for 32
//Instead of doing this??

if(A[1] & (1 << 0)){} //will also give me the state for 32


//Ultimately
if(A[0] & (1 << n)){} //will give me the n-th bit of my continuous block of memory??
```

I want to avoid indexing as that would require me to use things like division and modulo. My question is am I able to access the bits of next element of an array using bit shift operations? and ultimately change them?

```
A[0] = A[0] | (1 << n);
```

here is my full code:

```
/*
 *
 * @author Matthew Pecko
 * 12/29/2020
 *
 * Seive of Eratosthenes in C
 *
 * Define MIN as 0, and MAX to be the upper bound
 * of the prime range (in decimal)
 *
 * Define diff as (max - min) + 1
 *
 * The number of bytes we will need can be found:
 * numberOfBytes = diff/32
 * trueNumber = ceil(numberOfBytes)
 *
 * Calulate the true number of bytes and define it as SIZE
 *
 * A number's state can be retrieved:
 * state[0] & (1 << 0) -- will get state for 0
 * state[0] & (1 << 1) -- will get state for 1
 * state[0] & (1 << 2) -- will get state for 2
 * state[0] & (1 << n) -- will get state for n
 *
 *
 *
 * We want to seive the range from [0,sqrt(diff)]
 * we will stick with [0,diff] for now
 *
 */


#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

#define MIN 2
#define MAX 70
#define SIZE 1

void print(int* a);

int main(){
    //int* state = calloc(SIZE, 4);
    int* state = malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);
    int i, j, counter;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) state[i] = 0; 
        
    i = 2;
    while(i<=MAX){
        //printf("ADEBUG i: %d \n", i);
        if(!(state[0] & (1 << i))){
            j = i*i;
        //printf("DEBUG i: %d \n", i);
        //printf("DEBUG j: %d \n", j);
            counter = 0;
            while(j <= MAX+1){
                state[0] = state[0] | (1 << (j));
                counter++;
                printf("number I am on: %d \n", i);
                printf("multiple: %d \n", counter);
                printf("number to toggle (j): %d \n", j);
                j = (i*i) + counter*i;
            }   
        }
        printf("STEP: %d RESULT--------------------------- \n", i);
        print(state);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    printf("RESULT--------------------------- \n");
    print(state);
}

void print(int* a){
    int i;
    i = 2;
    do{
        if(!(a[0] & (1 << i))){
            printf("The state of %d is: \t true \n", i);
        }else{
            printf("The state of %d is: \t false \n", i);
        }   
        i++;
    }while(i <= MAX);
}
```

I understand there are some differences between malloc() and calloc(), so I tried using both:

```
int* state = malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) state[i] = 0;
```

and

```
int* state = calloc(SIZE, 4);
```

I believe my issue lies in the fact that I cannot access a continuous block of memory using only bit shifting operations, or the fact that I am using gcc and it might use little endian bit rep. I would really like to avoid using division and modulo to find my index for state[index], however I can try to do this and then try and change it to bitshift left operations since I believe I will only be dividing by numbers that can be represented as 2^n.

Comment: You'll need to use division & modulo.

Comment: @ScottHunter ok thank you, could you explain why though? I mean I thought malloc() allocates a continuous block of memory... So as long as I don't go over SIZE*4 bytes, I will be in that memory block?

Comment: Q: am I able to access the bits of next element of an array using bit shift operations? A: No.   Q: I want to avoid ... things like division and modulo.  A: Why?  "%" is your Friend.

Comment: Avoid using signed types for bit operations. You do not want the sign interfering with shifts, among other issues.

Comment: The shift operator operates on just its operands.  It will not magically read bits from other memory locations adjacent to where its operand was read from.

Comment: @ChrisDodd why won't it read bits from adj. memory locations? It's a block of memory after all... Why should it matter if the bit is in one address or the next. Is this the same reason why I can't use bitwise operations on pointers

Comment: @johnSmith563: In `A[0] & (1 << 32)`, `1 << 32` is calculated first. This operation is not affected by anything else in the expression. `1` is an `int` and is presumably 32 bits in your C implementation. Then `1 << 32` is undefined because the C standard says shifting a value by as many or more bits than are in it is not defined. Even if your C implementation produces some value, say `x`, then the rest of the expression is `A[0] & x`. Nothing in this says to go get `A[1]` instead of `A[0]` if `x` is one value or another. It just says “Get the value of `A[0]` and bitwise-AND it with `x`.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you very much! I wish I could mark your response as the answer.

Comment: Its not a block of memory -- its a piece of data that was read from a block of memory.  When it comes time to do the actual shift or mask, it is just a value and the association with the memory it was read from is gone.

Comment: Two is the only odd prime.  If you treat 2 specially then you can halve the size of your array by just holding primality flags for the odd numbers.  Bit n shows the primality of (2n+3).

Answer (score 3):

Do not be afraid of modulo operations with **constant** operands (like `x % 8`).
Any modern compiler *will* optimize it as bitwise-and with a mask.
See https://godbolt.org/z/ehjMbo

I suggest using a long fixed-size unsigned integer type like `uint64_t` from `stdint.h`. Use `uint32_t` if you use 32-bit machine.

Do not use `int` due to implementation-specific size and a risk of undefined behaviors due to overflows like `1<<32` or even `1 << 31`.

```
int limit = ...;
uint64_t *data = calloc((limit + 63) / 64, sizeof *data);

// reading bit X
bool bitX = (data[X / 64u] >> (X % 64u)) & 1;

// setting bit Y
data[Y / 64u] |= (1ull << (Y % 64u));
```

`64u` is used to force promoting `X` to unsigned type to let use the optimal division algorithm.

Comment: Note that if `X` or `Y` is a signed value and the compiler can't determine that it is not negative, it won't be able to use a fast mask for `/` or `%` and will need to muck with the sign bit.  You can ensure that doesn't happen by using `64U` instead of `64` for the divisor (ensuring an unsigned div/mod that can be done with just a shift or mask).  In your godbolt example, see what happens when you change the `8` to `8u`...

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be manipulating individual bits, then you should be comfortable using bitwise operations to shift and mask instead of using `/` and `%`.

As @tstanisl indicates, you should use a fixed-size data type instead of `int`, and it's a little clearer to use an unsigned type if you aren't treating the sign bit as a sign.

For 32=bit words, for example:

```
static inline void setBit(uint32_t *data, size_t bitIndex)
{
    data[bitIndex>>5] |= ((uint32_t)1) << (bitIndex&31);
}

static inline void clearBit(uint32_t *data, size_t bitIndex)
{
    data[bitIndex>>5] &= ~(((uint32_t)1) << (bitIndex&31));
}

static inline bool getBit(uint32_t *data, size_t bitIndex)
{
    return (bool)((data[bitIndex>>5] >> (bitIndex&31)) & 1);
}
```